# Pyspark dataframe returns different results each time I run

Tags: python, pyspark

Everytime I run a simple groupby pyspark returns different values, even though I haven't done any modification on the dataframe.

Here is the code I am using:

```
df = spark.sql('select * from data ORDER BY document_id')
df_check = df.groupby("vacina_descricao_dose").agg(count('paciente_id').alias('paciente_id_count')).orderBy(desc('paciente_id_count')).select("*")
df_check.show(df_check.count(),False)
```

I ran df_check.show() 3 times and the column paciente_id_count gives different values everytime: [show results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdW2I.png) (I cut the tables so It would be easier to compare).

How do I prevent this?

Comment: What does `df_check.show()` returns (excluding `df_check.count()`)?

Comment: .show() returns a new dataframe with grouped data. I use the parameters df_check.count() and 'False' so it returns all rows.

Answer (score 0):

The .show() does not compute the whole operations.

Maybe you could try the following (if the final number of rows fits in your drive memory):

```
df = spark.sql('select * from data ORDER BY document_id')
df_check = df.groupby("vacina_descricao_dose").agg(count('paciente_id').alias('paciente_ id_count')).orderBy(desc('paciente_id_count')).select("*")
df_check.toPandas()
```

Comment: Apparently it didn't work either :(


[Image link](https://i.postimg.cc/xj71Xxk0/stackoverflow2.png)